# Conditionally replace values across multiple columns based on string match in a separate column

Tags: r, stringr, dplyr, across

I'm trying to conditionally replace values in multiple columns based on a string match in a different column but I'd like to be able to do so in a single line of code using the across() function but I keep getting errors that don't quite make sense to me.  I feel like this is probably a simple solution so if anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be fantastic!

```
df <- data.frame("type" = c("Park", "Neighborhood", "Airport", "Park", "Neighborhood", "Neighborhood"),
               "total" = c(34, 56, 75, 89, 21, 56),
               "group_a" = c(30, 26, 45, 60, 3, 46),
               "group_b" = c(4, 30, 30, 29, 18, 10))

# working but not concise
df %>%
  mutate(total = ifelse(str_detect(type, "Park"), NA, total),
         group_a = ifelse(str_detect(type, "Park"), NA, group_a),
         group_b = ifelse(str_detect(type, "Park"), NA, group_b))

  
# concise but not working
df %>% mutate(across(total, group_a, group_b), ifelse(str_detect(type, "Park"), NA, .))
```

## Update

We got a solution that works with my dummy dataset but is not working with my real data, so I am going to share a small snippet of my real data frame with the numbers changed and organization names hidden. When I run this line of code (`df %>% mutate(across(c(Attempts, Canvasses, Completes)), ~ifelse(str_detect(long_name, "park-cemetery"), NA, .))`) on these data, I get the following error message:

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..2`. x Input `..2` must be a
> vector, not a `formula` object. i Input `..2` is
> `~ifelse(str_detect(long_name, "park-cemetery"), NA, .)`.

This a small sample of the data that produces this error:

```
df <- structure(list(Org = c("OrgName", "OrgName", "OrgName", "OrgName", 
"OrgName", "OrgName", "OrgName", "OrgName", "OrgName", "OrgName"
), nCode = c("M34", "R36", "R46", "X29", "M31", "K39", "Q12", 
"Q39", "X41", "K27"), Attempts = c(100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100), Canvasses = c(80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 
80, 80, 80), Completes = c(50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 
50), van_nocc_id = c(999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 
999, 999), van_name = c("M-Upper West Side", "SI-Rosebank", "SI-Tottenville", 
"BX-park-cemetery-etc-Bronx", "M-Stuyvesant Town-Cooper Village", 
"BK-Kensington", "Q-Broad Channel", "Q-Lindenwood", "BX-Wakefield", 
"BK-East New York"), boro_short = c("M", "SI", "SI", "BX", "M", 
"BK", "Q", "Q", "BX", "BK"), long_name = c("Upper West Side", 
"Rosebank", "Tottenville", "park-cemetery-etc-Bronx", "Stuyvesant Town-Cooper Village", 
"Kensington", "Broad Channel", "Lindenwood", "Wakefield", "East New York"
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

## Final update

The curse of the misplaced closing bracket! Thanks to everyone for your help... the correct solution was `df %>% mutate(across(c(Attempts, Canvasses, Completes), ~ifelse(str_detect(long_name, "park-cemetery"), NA, .)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the newly introduced function `across` (which is the correct way to approach this task), you have to specify *inside* `across` itself the function you want to apply. In this case the function `ifelse(...)` has to be a purrr-style lambda (so starting with `~`). Check out `across` [documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html) and look for the arguments `.cols` and `.fns`.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(across(c(total, group_a, group_b), ~ifelse(str_detect(type, "Park"), NA, .)))
```

Output

```
#           type total group_a group_b
# 1         Park    NA      NA      NA
# 2 Neighborhood    56      26      30
# 3      Airport    75      45      30
# 4         Park    NA      NA      NA
# 5 Neighborhood    21       3      18
# 6 Neighborhood    56      46      10
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!  Interestingly this works for my dummy dataset but not when I apply the exact same syntax to my much larger real dataset... I keep getting this error message: Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..2`.
x Input `..2` must be a vector, not a `formula` object.
i Input `..2` is `~ifelse(str_detect(long_name, "park-cemetery"), NA, .)`` Any thoughts on why it might be throwing this error with a larger dataset?

Comment: Are you still passing the variables you want to mutate with a `c(variable_1, variable_2, ...)`?

Comment: Yup, exactly like that.

Comment: Can you share a sample of your bigger data using the `dput` function and pasting the output in you question? Also, could you paste the code you used to get that error?

Comment: Posted an update with a sample of the real (but modified) data. Thanks again for your insights!

Comment: The problem is that you need to specify the `~ifelse` lambda function *inside* `across` as its second argument (the `.fns` argument, see documentation), not inside `mutate`. You have to shift one bracket to do so: `df %>% mutate(across(c(Attempts, Canvasses, Completes), ~ifelse(str_detect(long_name, "park-cemetery"), NA, .)))`. My original answer is in fact correct

Comment: Ahh, the curse of the misplaced closing bracket!  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Here a data.table solution.

```
require(data.table)
df <- data.frame("type" = c("Park", "Neighborhood", "Airport", "Park", "Neighborhood", "Neighborhood"),
               "total" = c(34, 56, 75, 89, 21, 56),
               "group_a" = c(30, 26, 45, 60, 3, 46),
               "group_b" = c(4, 30, 30, 29, 18, 10))

setDT(df)
df[type == "Park", c("total", "group_a", "group_b") := NA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: that didn't take long to figure out! Just needed to place the columns in a vector:

```
# concise AND working!
df %>% mutate(across(c(total, group_a, group_b)), ifelse(str_detect(type, "Park"), NA, .))
```

I had tried this initially but placed the columns in quotes... don't do that :)

Comment: Actually this answer doesn't work because you get a column named `felse(str_detect(type, "Park"), NA, .)` (at least in my case). Check out my answer above instead.